# No me permite conectar un elemento VideoView de xml a la clase java - Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio

Estoy trabajando con un activity tipo Navigation Drawer, y quiero incorporar en el fragment home o principal un elemento VideoViewer para situar un video de YouTube ahí.

El problema está cuando trato de conectar la parte grafica xml con la parte logica

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

private HomeViewModel homeViewModel;
VideoView video;

public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                         ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    homeViewModel =
            ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(HomeViewModel.class);
    View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_facul, container, false);
    final TextView textView = root.findViewById(R.id.text_home);
    homeViewModel.getText().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), new Observer<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(@Nullable String s) {
            textView.setText(s);
        }
    });
    return root;

    video = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.video_facultad);
}
```

}

Me lanza rojo en "findViewByID..."

```
Cannot resolve method 'findViewById' in 'HomeFragment'
```

Comment: Los fragment necesitan el elemento `View`, para unir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes añadir el elemento `getView()`

```
video = (VideoView)getView().findViewById(R.id.video_facultad);`
```